# Forcing javascript execution after partial postback (update panel)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel and want to execute a javascript action after postback, all my pages have use a global `pageLoad(sender, args)` so I can't use a `pageLoad(sender, args)` for this particular event, I tried the 2 following approaches:

```
//Global pageLoad, executes in all pages
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    myGlobalCode();

    try {localPageLoad(sender, args)} 
    catch (err) {}
}

// This is in the page with the update panel
function localPageLoad(sender, args) {
    if ($('#AfterPostback').val() == 'SHOWTOOLBOX')
        // etc....
}
```

The problem here is with syncronicity, if I set debug alerts in this code everything works fine, but if I execute without alerts it does nothing, so I guess it has something to do with document completion

The other thing I tryed is to use ScriptManager inside the event fired by the partial postback:

```
    cstext1.Append(String.Format("alert('CS TOOL'); showToolbox({0});", AfterPostbackParams.Value))
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), "InitPage", cstext1.ToString(), True)
```

I find the same problem, if I set debug alerts everything is ok, if I run the code like this it doesn't work.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: As part of the solution I had to take the GridView that triggers the UpdatePanel outside the UpdatePanel itself, this carried a number of unwanted consecuences that is taking several hours to solve but at least I solved async rendering problems

Answer (score 0):

could you use the following?

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest();
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx

Comment: The same problem, so it turns out it's not exactly a problem of syncronicity in function calls but syncronicity in rendering, the javascript function is running and working, but apparently it happens before updatepanel has finished rendering, so I can't see the result

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing update panels and additional javascript execution, I've always had more luck using `RegisterStartupScript` versus `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.  Example:

```
cstext1.Append(String.Format("showToolbox({0});", AfterPostbackParams.Value));
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "InitPage", cstext1.ToString(), True);
```

The beautiful thing about UpdatePanels is they are easy to diagnose problems with by using either fiddler, or any modern browser developer tool's network tab.  Since an `UpdatePanel` simply works by sending back the HTML that is replaced into the panel div, you can easily see what is coming back to ensure it makes sense.